# Exclude npm module dependency?

Tags: dependencies, phantomjs, environment-variables, karma-runner, decoupling

In the project that I'm working on, we use the Karma test runner, and  [karma-phantomjs-launcher](https://github.com/karma-runner/karma-phantomjs-launcher) to help us run tests using PhantomJS.  Recently, we have discovered that the PhantomJS version that gets pulled down as a dependency to karma-phantomjs-launcher `1.9.8` has some issues that were making our tests fail.  Fortunately, karma-phantomjs-launcher allows us to set the `PHANTOMJS_BIN` environment variable to point to an alternative PhantomJS binary to use instead, which made upgrading to `2.0.0` rather simple.

This is all fine and dandy, but when our continuous integration environment attempts to build our project, it is still pulling down the PhantomJS `1.9.8` binary when doing an `npm install`, since it needs to install `karma-phantomjs-launcher` which depends on PhantomJS `1.9.8`.

Since our build server has been configured to use the `2.0.0` binary that we've given it, there really is no need to download the `1.9.8` binary, and I would prefer that it did not do that if possible.

So is there any way that I could configure my package.json to tell `karma-phantomjs-launcher` that it does not need to pull down its PhantomJS `1.9.8` dependency?

Comment: Are you by any chance using TravisCI or CircleCI? We've solved the above issue on Circle, utilising a solution originating from a Travis setup. If the answer is *no*, then I doubt said solution would do you much good.

Comment: Having this same issue with our builds (using mocha-phantomjs). @KasperLewau, I'd be interested to hear how you guys solved it on CI? It's definitely the bottleneck in our npm install.

Answer (score 1):

Use a module without the dependency:

> phantomjs package downloads PhantomJS from the third-party website. While this download can be prevented by making sure that you have correct PhantomJS version in the PATH, this is not always practical.
>
> [This package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/karma-phantomjs-launcher-nonet) removes phantomjs from dependencies and requires you to set the path to PhantomJS explicitly.

Or remove it from the default package.json. For example, on a Linux shell:

```
cd node_modules/karma-phantomjs-launcher
vi package.json
```

Remove the `dependencies` declaration:

```
  "dependencies": {
    "phantomjs": "~1.9"
    },
```

**References**

- [npm package karma-phantomjs-launcher-nonet](https://www.npmjs.com/package/karma-phantomjs-launcher-nonet)